# Is it necessary to index features when loading WFS layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wfs

There is ~85k features in a WFS layer coming from the LAN server with a 1 gb ethernet link. However, I have to wait a very uncomfortable amount of time for the layer to be indexed when I load it.

Since I don't really have to bother with the transfer speed, can it truly run live?

In ArcMap, I have set the cache expiry to 0 (Data Interoperability).

The data is stored in PostgreSQL/PostGIS and is served by MapServer 7.0.4 (server is running Windows Server 2012).

While indexing, I can see that MapServer takes 2-3% of the processor, and uses disk at less than 1 MB/s (server-side)

Client-side, 25-30% CPU (~90% max. frequency), 6-8 MB/s

Data is transfered over the network at ~ 40 mbit/s (on a gigabit link)

So it seems that the bottleneck is on the client side.

Comment: I would be struggling to think of a situation where an index (spatial index that is) wouldn't be a good idea. What is the data stored in while waiting for the WFS server to dish it out? Your bottleneck isn't likely to be LAN unless you've got a screaming NIC somewhere but can be anything on the remote computer from a slow hard drive to virus scanner. Can you remote desktop to the server and watch the resource monitor whilst serving? That might get you barking up the right tree - or at least in the right forest.

Comment: You had a tag for QGIS and mentioned it in your title but not question body so I removed it to prevent your question being too broad.  If you wish to ask about QGIS as well then just do that as a separate question.

Comment: Edited my question to include the informations about ressources.